# C++ SFINAE - Resolution priority between std::is_arithmetic and std::is_same

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, sfinae, enable-if

I'm using SFINAE to build a rudimentary serialization library.

Let's say I have a class that implements a generic `process` method, that reads in any type (allowing for user-extension) and serializes it. I'm using `std::enable_if` to specialize this method to different template argument types. Here's an example:

```
class OutputSerializer
{
public:
    OutputSerializer(std::ostream& str) : stream(str) {}

private:
    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void>::type
    process(T&& arg) {
        stream.write(&arg, sizeof(arg));
    }

//More specializations here

    std::ostream& stream;
};
```

I want to optimize this method for booleans, by making the output stream store 1 byte, instead of `sizeof(bool)` bytes. Similarly to how I did before, I add a new template specialization:

```
class OutputSerializer
{
public:
    OutputSerializer(std::ostream& str) : stream(str) {}

private:
    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void>::type
    process(T&& arg) {
        stream.write(&arg, sizeof(arg));
    }

    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, bool>::value, void>::type
    process(T&& arg) {
        stream.write(&arg, 1);
    }

    std::ostream& stream;
};
```

Now, a question arises. `std::is_arithmetic<bool>` is also supposed to return `true`. So which of the two specializations will be given priority during name resolution?

Keep in mind, this is only a theoretical question. I know of more ways to make sure this method does what I want it to, such as specializing the template itself for bool, like this:

```
template<>
void process<bool>(bool&& arg) {
    stream.write(&arg, 1);
}
```

or by adding an extra check in the more generic case, like this:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_arithmetic<T>::value
    && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value, void>::type
process(T&& arg) {
    stream.write(&arg, sizeof(arg));
}
```

Or at least, I'm pretty sure these would work. Feel free to call me out on it if I'm wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You need the `&& !std::is_same` otherwise you end up with two `void process(bool)`.  You can't have two functions with the same name and signature.  Of course, you could just use `if (std::is_same...` inside the function and the compiler would optimize it correctly, saving you lots of headache.

Comment: If `sizeof(bool) != 1` then you have an undefined behaviour in `stream.write(&arg, 1);` right?

Comment: Why not just make a non-template overload, `void process(bool)`? Non-templates take precedence over templates, other things equal.

Comment: @freakish: Not undefined behavior, it just won't always work correctly.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Well, if he doesn't deserialize that data then it's ok. But as soon as he tries then it's UB, right? But I guess this can be fixed with something like `stream.write(arg ? '1' : '0', 1);` and proper deserialization. Also are there any guarantees about `sizeof(bool)`? I mean shouldn't passing by value be more efficient?

Comment: @freakish: It would still not result in undefined behavior, you'd end up with an "unspecified value".

Comment: @DietrichEpp What's the difference?

Comment: @freakish: "Undefined behavior" has a special technical meaning, and it means that your program could do anything at all.  It's the most serious type of error in a program because you can't predict what the program will do.  "Unspecified value" just means that we don't know what value is stored in the `bool`.  It could be `true`, `false`, or something *else*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither has any sort of priority.  Both templates will  result in the function `void process(bool)` and the call will be ambiguous.

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2eaf0597804539e1)

Adding an explicit specialization for `bool` won't work either, since there's no clear base template to specialize.  You need to add more conditions to the `std::is_arithmetic` version of the template, or better just provide a non-template overload for `bool`.  Functions do have priority over function templates, so a non-template version will be chosen by overload resolution.

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3163cd058f799c2d)